# DSpace OAI-PMH XML Import

Tags: dspace, oai, oai-pmh

I am changing my OAI Data Provider from jOAI to DSpace. My expectation was that I could easily import the metadata, which is available as XML, into DSpace. But this seems not to be the case. I always get the error message

> Unknown metadata schema in heading

My XML File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<olac:olac xmlns:olac="http://www.language-archives.org/OLAC/1.1/"
           xmlns="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
           xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.language-archives.org/OLAC/1.1/
                http://www.language-archives.org/OLAC/1.1/olac.xsd">

  <title>My Title</title>
  <creator>Project</creator>
  <subject>My Subject</subject>
  <language xsi:type="olac:language" olac:code="de">German</language>
  <description>A lot of text</description>
  <publisher>Pub</publisher>
  <format>XML/TEI</format>
  <date>2016-10-07</date>
  <coverage></coverage>
  <identifier>https://github.com/MyProject/identifier>
  <type>Text</type>
  <rights>The original documents are in the public domain. XML/TEI documents are available for non-commercial users (CLARIN PUB+ID+BY+NC+LRT+NORED+ND+DEP+SA)</rights>
</olac:olac>
```

This worked for me in the past. Unfortunately I can not find any good description how the files should be structured.

Any help?

Regards
SimGeh

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**
Try this link: [dcorepackager.herokuapp.com](https://dcorepackager.herokuapp.com/). You can replace the default links in there and after you have downloaded the zip file, unzip it and view the `dublin_core.xml` file. That is how your XML should be structured.

In your example, your XML should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<dublin_core schema="dc">
  <dcvalue element="title" qualifier="none" language="en">My Title</dcvalue>
  <dcvalue element="creator" qualifier="none">Project</dcvalue>
  <dcvalue element="date" qualifier="issued">2016-10-07</dcvalue>
  <dcvalue element="subject" qualifier="none" language="en">My Subject</dcvalue>
  …
  …
</dublin_core>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. Should you have a working xml file for harvesting to OpenAIRE from Dspace? Thx.

Comment: I created chat room for dspace. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227459/dspace-repository-guide-help-room